# Solving an equation with different bases, each to an unknown power, but with a third value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is a relatively straightforward question, but neither myself nor my colleagues are able to come up with a tidy solution without brute force:

Represent $x$ algebraically, given the equation

$$4^{2x-1} = 3^{x+3}+1$$

I have looked around the internet and I cannot seem to find any method to properly solving this problem. It's really the +1 at the end that messes everything up for me. Help!

Comment: I doubt this has a convenient closed form.  Numerical methods yield $x\approx 2.7980335838079236320$ if that helps.

Comment: @lulu Yea I was trying to see if I could reverse solve the numerical solution on wolfram, but I got nowhere.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the given equation? In this kind of exercises with different bases use to be helpful the substitution $t=base_1/base_2,$ which is not the case here :(